# Differentiability in $R^2$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

> Let $U=\{(x,y) \text{ in } \mathbb{R}^2 : x_2 + y_2 < 4\}$, and let $f(x,y)= \sqrt{4-x_2-y_2}$.
>   Prove that $f$ is differentiable, and find its derivative.

I do know how to prove it is differentiable at a specific point in $\mathbb{R}^2$, but I could not generalize it to prove it differentiable on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Any hint?

Comment: At what point can you prove that the function is differentiable? The function is not defined in $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: What is your definition of differentiability on $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: Sorry, i was not clear enough  i thought about the theorem that says if the partial derivatives of a function are continuous on some open set, then the function will be differentiable at each point of that open set

Comment: Are you looking for total differentiability of the function, directional differentiability of the function, or partial differentiabiltiy with respect to $x$ and $y$? Each one of these will require an answer of a different level of complexity.

Answer (score -3):

A function is differentiable in $U$ if it is differentiable at every point in $U$. So what you need to do is pick an arbitrary $(a,b) \in U$ and show that $f$ is differentiable at $(a,b)$.

Comment: if i proved that it is differentiable on U, how can i find its derivative?

Comment: Well, it would have two partial derivatives. To find the partial derivative with respect to $x$ you just treat $y$ as a constant and differentiate as you would do for a single variable. Same, but excanging $x$, $y$, for derivative with respect to $y$.